# sed search and extract specific field using regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Hi i'm having issue trying to use sed to search a very large file for a specfic string and extract the middle field, Here is what i had tried:

for example, i am looking for the string `$BBB.*,55`

```
sed -n '/^$BBB.*,\b55\b/p',
```

this would return the specific line, but how do i tweak the regex to extract only the `JOB1` from it? appreciate any kind advice

```
$AAA.JOB1,15

$AAA.JOB6,25

$BBB.JOB1,55 # I want to extract JOB1 from this line

$BBB.JOB2,59

CCC.CPU1,16

CCC.CPU4,18
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to use `\$`, because `$` is a `metacharacter` in `regex`;
And then, you can use `capture group` to keep what you want.
Try this for `GNU sed`:

```
$ cat test.txt 
$AAA.JOB1,15
$AAA.JOB6,25
$BBB.JOB1,55
$BBB.JOB2,59
CCC.CPU1,16
CCC.CPU4,18
$ sed -nr 's/^\$BBB\.([^,]*),55/\1/p' test.txt
JOB1
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that `\1` in the *replace* string is normally referred to as a *back reference* which restores what is captured by your *capture group* in the *find* portion of the `sed` substitution. (you can use multiple capture groups and *back references* in order, e.g. `\1`, `\2`, ...)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract **JOB1** from searched **$BBB.JOB1,55**.
You can use `awk`,

```
$ awk -F[.,] '/\$BBB.*,55/{print $2}' test.txt
JOB1
```

If the patterns you want to search are assigned to variables, use methods as followed,

```
$ var1=$BBB
$ var2=55
$ awk -F[.,] -v v=$var1".*,"$var2 '$0 ~ v{print $2}' test.txt
JOB1
```

Comment: this is working!  Thanks alot. side track here, i trying to get this working in bash shell. where "$BBB" and "55" is a variable; say var1="$BBB" and var2 is "55". awk variable substitution in regex is driving me nuts, using the recommended method via the -v; here is goes awk -F[]., -v v1="$var1" -v v2="$var2" '/\v1.*,v2/{print $2}' test.txt, but it did'nt work however i tried, any clues here???

Comment: @user3330821, see my answer for your further request.

Answer (score 0):

with `grep`:

```
grep -Po "(?<=\.)([^\.]*[^,])(?=,)" filename
```

output:

```
JOB1
JOB6
JOB1
JOB2
CPU1
CPU4
```